# In directive template, inside ng-repeat scope not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a directive as follows,

```
  angular.module("sample").directive("sampleDir", [
    "$compile", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          options: '=',
          source: '='
       },
        templateUrl: "sample.html"
      };
    }
  ]);
```

sample.html

```
  <div ng-repeat="row in source" class="{{$parent.options.Class}}">
    <label value="{{row.label}}">{{row.label}}</label>
  </div>
```

Here inside template "source" parameter i can use as such. However, "options" parameter need to be fetched from parent scope. If i am creating another div outside, then options parameter i can get as such.

I tried adding another div outside this ng-repeat div and tried to access "options" parameter is working fine.

```
  <div class="{{options.Class}}">
    <div ng-repeat="row in source">
      <label value="{{row.label}}">{{row.label}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But why it is not working with ng-repeat div?

How can i remove $parent and use "options" parameter as such?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9837). It's happening when you use `replace: true` and ngRepeat on the top element of the directive. So the ngRepeat is bound to the outer scope instead of the isolated scope.

You can resolve it by either not using replace or adding an element to the top of the directive.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the scope variable name "options" might be conflicting. Try changing the scope variable of the directive to something else.

For eg: Your scope definition can change to this

```
scope: {
          sampleOptions: '=',
          source: '='
       },
```

in case you are stuck with any syntax related issue doing this, [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope) will be helpful

Comment: Thanks. But this is not the reason. Please see the updated question